# Контравариантность обобщенных делегатов С#

Tags: c#, generics, делегаты

```
  using System;

// Контрвариантность обобщений.
// Контрвариантность обобщений в C# 4.0 ограничена делегатами.

namespace Generics
{
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }

class Program
{
    delegate void MyDelegate<in T>(T a);  // in - Для аргумента.

    public static void CatUser(Animal animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(animal.GetType().Name);
    }

    static void Main()
    {

        MyDelegate<Animal> delegateAnimal = new MyDelegate<Animal>(CatUser);
        //MyDelegate<Cat> delegateCat = delegateAnimal;     

        MyDelegate<Cat> delegateCat=new MyDelegate<Animal>(CatUser);
        delegateAnimal(new Animal());
        delegateCat(new Cat());

        delegateAnimal(new Cat());
        //    delegateCat(new Animal()); // Невозможно.

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

почему нельзя вызвать delegateCat(new Animal()); ? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Потому что важен тип объявления, а не рантайм-тип.

> ```
> MyDelegate<Cat> delegateCat=new MyDelegate<Animal>(CatUser);
> ```

Такое присваивание возможно, поскольку любая функция, принимающая животное, может в качестве него принять кота.

- Мне нужен дрессировщик котов.
- Универсальный дрессировщик животных подойдёт?
- Да.

> почему нельзя вызвать `delegateCat(new Animal());`?

Потому что компилятор видит функцию, принимающую кота. Потенциально такая функция может вызывать методы кота, отсутствующие у животного. Компилятор не знает, делает ли так функция - он просто верит программисту, написавшему, что функции нужен именно кот, а не любое животное.

- У нас замечательный дрессировщик котов.
- Он может выдрессировать неизвестного зверька?
- Неизвестно, поэтому зверёк не годится. Приходите с котом.

Comment: Красивая аналогия, кстати.

Answer (score 0):

Если упрощенно, то Animal не может заменить по типу своего наследника Cat. А Cat родителя может. Потому в Callback-е ожидается ответ с типом Cat, и подав на вход Animal получим InvalidCastException или что-то вроде.