# Дженерики, ошибка "Wrong 2nd argument type"

Tags: java, generics

```
public static <K, V> boolean addToGroupMap(K key, V value, Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>> checkMap){

    assert checkMap!=null;
    boolean result = false;

    Collection<V> vList = checkMap.get(key);
    if (vList==null){
        checkMap.put(key, new ArrayList<V>(Collections.singleton(value)));
    }else {
        vList.add(value);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Думал, что более менее разобрался с дженериками, однако, в упор не понимаю, почему в строке: `checkMap.put(key, new ArrayList<V>(Collections.singleton(value)));` Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.ArrayList', required: '? extends java.util.Collection

Сначала в сигнатуре метода было : `K key, V value, Map<K, List<V>> checkMap`. Однако теперь надо, чтобы в значении мапы была именно коллекция. При этом, нет желания менять в куче кода `List<>` в checkMap'e на `Collection<>`, да и почему это надо делать, если лист имплементирует коллекцию?

**UDP:** Также, возникает вопрос. Почему, если заменить в сигнатуре `? extends Collection` на `? super Collection`, пропадает доступ к методам коллекции? Ведь вроде `? super Collection` ограничивает самой коллекцией и ее родителями?

Comment: Предположу, что ? extends Collection имеет право оказаться, например, Set, и в этом случае произойдет очевидная логическая ошибка. C просто `Collection<V>` такого быть не может.

Comment: А какая разница, если что Set, что List имплементируют коллекцию?

Comment: надо заменить на `new List<V>`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, забавный комментарий, конечно. Только зачем мне реализовывать интерфейс, если в Java это давно за меня сделали?)

Comment: Ну так и сделай `Map<K, Collection<V>> checkMap`, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда во всех мапах в коде, придется заменить List на Collection. В общем-то это не самая страшная проблема, но хотелось бы разобраться.

Comment: @I.Perevoz, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546907/178988 - в твоём случае вместо делегата коллекция, но идея та же - каст в такую сторону невозможен - некий наследник коллекции не обязан быть ArrayList. По идее нужно [что-то такое](http://ideone.com/t8cMX9), но как это сделать я не знаю (и ничего хорошего не гуглится).

Comment: @Qwertiy фабрику же использовать надо было. Это и для C# работает.

Comment: `<? extends Collection>` означает `неизвестный тип` (расширяющий в данном случае Collection). Поскольку тип не известен, то и неизвестно является ли он супер-классом ArrayList-а (или любого другого класса коллекции) или нет. А раз неизвестно, то и Ваши манипуляции небезопасны. `Запомните, дети: тарелька и вилька пишется без мягкого знака, а сол и фасол с мягким знаком. Запомните это дети, ибо понять этого не возможно!`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, фабрику списков?)))

Comment: @Qwertiy а что в имеете против?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это как-то странно...

Comment: @I.Perevoz то, что формально этот метод вы можете применить к Set<V>, и работаете **не** с коллекцией в чистом виде.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Забудем пока про конкретно ваш код и рассмотрим более простой пример. Допустим, есть вот такие классы:

```
// Для демонстрации иерархии типов
class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }

// Для демонстрации контейнера
class S<V> {
  private V value;

  public V get() { return value; }
  public void set(V value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Рассмотрим такой контейнер, как `S<? extends B>`. Каким будет возвращаемое значение для метода `get`? Этот метод вернет что-то, что является наследником B. То есть, что бы метод `get` ни вернул - это что-то можно записать в переменную типа B.

```
S<? extends B> s;
B v = s.get(); // Значение типа ? extends B всегда можно записать в переменную типа B
```

Теперь рассмотрим метод set. Кажется, что все нормально? Но давайте сделаем вот так:

```
S<? extends B> s = new S<C>();
s.set(new B()); // Ошибка - значение типа B не может быть передано как параметр типа C
```

Здесь я создал конкретный контейнер для примера. Даже если на самом деле используется `S<B>` - компилятор должен обеспечить корректность кода в любом случае.

Теперь рассмотрим такой контейнер как `S<? super B>`. Метод `set` у него можно вызвать с параметром типа `B`:

```
S<? super B> s;
s.set(new B()); // Значение типа B всегда можно передать как ? super B
```

А вот метод get нормально вызвать не получится:

```
S<? super B> s = new S<A>();
B v = s.get(); // Ошибка - попытались значение типа A записать в переменную типа B
```

В итоге получается, что get-методы требуют отношения extends, а set-методы требуют отношения super. Если вашему коду нужно использовать оба типа методов - придется определять оба отношения одновременно, т.е. оставить просто `<B>`.

---

Возвращаюсь к вашему коду, можно заметить, что из параметра `checkMap` вы одновременно получаете данные (get) - и передаете их ему (put). Поэтому, вы не можете использовать `? extends ...` в определении параметра. Единственный способ сделать оба вызова рабочими - использовать конкретный тип данных. Например, `Map<K, Collection<V>>`.

Если же вам нужно работать с разными отображениями - то сам тип коллекции надо делать обобщенным: `Map<K, C>` где `C extends Collection<V>`. Для того чтобы создать такую коллекцию, вам нужно будет принимать фабрику или класс как параметр:

```
public static <K, V, C extends Collection<V>> boolean addToGroupMap(K key, V value, 
        Map<K, C> checkMap, Callable<? extends C> collectionFactory) {
    C vList = checkMap.get(key);
    checkMap.put(key, vList = collectionFactory.call());
}

public static <K, V, C extends Collection<V>> boolean addToGroupMap(K key, V value, 
        Map<K, C> checkMap, Class<? extends C> collectionClass) {
    C vList = checkMap.get(key);
    checkMap.put(key, vList = collectionClass.newInstance());
}
```

Смысл фабрики - в том, что ее создает тот код, который знает точный тип коллекции:

```
Map<K, List<V>> checkMap1 = new Map<>();
Callable<List<V>> factory1 = () -> new ArrayList<V>();

Map<K, Set<V>> checkMap2 = new Map<>();
Callable<Set<V>> factory2 = () -> new HashSet<V>();
```

Дальше фабрика по цепочке вызовов передается пока не придет в метод `addToGroupMap`.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы подсказать реализацию фабрики в Вашем случае? Просто я не понимаю, каким образом в данной ситуации фабрика узнает какую конкретно реализацию ей выбрать.

Comment: @I.Perevoz а фабрика не должна ее *выбирать*. Она должна ее ***знать***.

Comment: @I.Perevoz тот, кто *знает* конкретный тип коллекции - тот и создает фабрику.

Comment: Т.е., как я понял, в .put я инициализирую значение в Entry, а потом по ссылке добавляю в него элементы (если это необходимо)?

Comment: @I.Perevoz не понял о чем вы

Comment: Просто напишите vList = new ArrayList...А фабрику с калбаками выкинуть. Посмотрим что будет. new - это тоже как бы фабрика.

Comment: @Sergey будет ошибка компиляции. Потому что `ArrayList<V>` не обязательно реализует `C`.

Comment: А тогда с привидением типа? ((С) new ArrayList ...)?

Comment: @Sergey Поймите - если вдруг `C` - это `Set<V>`, то `ArrayList<V>` туда запихивать попросту неправильно!

Comment: А фабрика откуда возьмёт-то что-то подходящее? У неё такие же листы и сеты, как у new.

Comment: @Sergey я уже писал про это. Идея в том, что фабрику создает тот код, который знает точный тип коллекции.

Comment: Могли бы вы все-таки дополнить ответ реализацией фабрики? Суть проблемы, благодаря Вашему ответу понятна, но вот насчет: "Если же вам нужно работать с разными отображениями", хотелось бы немного конкретики.

Comment: Сдаётся мне автор точно знает, что там ArrayList. Нафига только с <? extends Collection> связался не понятно. Ну дело его.

Comment: @I.Perevoz как раз добавил это в ответ.

Comment: @Sergey. Лень менять тучу кода, умноженная на "интересно, почему же так?". Суть проблемы я понял, как раз хотел бы привести все в порядок.

Comment: @Sergey и это, если вы не заметили, был первым из возможных вариантов в ответе.