# Java generics как работает?

Tags: java, generics

Я пишу:

```
Class<? extends Task> a = n.getClass();
```

Метод `getClass()` должен вернуть объект описывающий класс и присвоить его переменной `а`.

Но вот это часть мне не понятна `Class<? extends Task>`. Что это за тип переменной такой и куда переменную `а` теперь вообще можно использовать?
Хочу понять как это работает. Помогите разобраться. 
особенно <**?** extends Task> знак вопроса убивает здесь что-то общее с тернарной операцией?

Comment: Это дженерики, почитайте про java generics и вам сразу все станет ясно

Comment: [прочтите](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do), если не боитесь английского. Все встанет на свои места.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361807/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-wildcard-%D0%B2-generics-java Здесь довольно хорошо объяснили

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588385/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-wrong-2nd-argument-type так же здесь в ответе очень явно понимается разница между extends и super

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Примеры**

- Обозначение типа параметра

```html
public static double sumOfList(List<? extends Number> list) {
  double s = 0.0;
  for (Number n : list)
    s += n.doubleValue();
  return s;
}
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
  for (Object elem: list)
    System.out.print(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

- Поле класса и тип возвращаемого значения

```
public class ClassContainer {
private List<? extends Number> list;

public ClassContainer(List<? extends Number> list){
  this.list = list;
}

public List<? extends Number> getList(){
  return this.list;
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Нет, что вы, нет здесь тернарной операции))
`? extends Object` - означает, что здесь может быть любой класс, унаследованный от `Object`. Вот аналогичная запись:

```
List<? extends Map<String, String>>
```

Answer (score 4):

В коде где используются обобщённые типы знак вопроса **?** называется шаблоном поиска ([wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)) и представляет собой неизвестный тип. Этот символ используется в различных ситуациях:

- обозначает тип параметра,
- поля класса или типа локальной переменной,
- тип возвращаемого значения.

Есть определённые ограничения его применения.

Comment: О! Спасибо! Это начинает проливать свет на проблему, а нельзя ли примеры добавить? Простите за наглость... как это может выглядеть в этих 3х случаях.