# Что такое generics methods в Java?

Tags: java, generics, методы

В классе Collections наткнулся на такую запись

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
        list.sort(null);
    }
```

Не думал что есть generic методы, решил прочитать про них в Oracle, пожалуй не смог понять, в связи с чем они появились и как работают.

(это не дубликат вопроса хотя так может показаться, я знаю для чего и как используют обобщения для классов, мне не было известно об использовании обобщения для методов)

Comment: Попробуйте почитать учебники.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/sberbank/blog/416413/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Java generics как работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590355/java-generics-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: это не дубликат, тема одна и та же, но суть вопросов разная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дженерики(генерики, generics, перевод - "общий, обобщенный") позволяют вам кастомизировать "общие" методы или классы для любого типа с которым вы работаете.

Допустим вам нужно создать метод который складывает вместе 2 типа. Для этого вы в интерфейсе создадите generic-метод:

```
public T Add<T>(T a, T b)
```

А в реализацях можете создать несколько разных методов:

```
public int Add(int a, int b)

public double Add(double a, double b)

public float Add(float a, float b)
```

В этом примере `<T>` должен заменятся на один и тот же тип данных.

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)
[Хорошая статья.](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2004-teorija-dzhenerikov-v-java-ili-gde-na-praktike-stavitjh-skobki)