# Различия между extend и super в Generics

Tags: java, generics

Для примера такой код:

```
public void add(List<? super Number> list) {
    list.add(1D); // можно
    list.add(new Object()); // нельзя
}
```

Почему так? Ведь здесь - `<? super Number>` - написано: "любой тип, являющийся супер-классом для `Number`". А работает всё наоборот: "любой тип - наследник `Number`". Что не так? Почему работает наоборот?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588385/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-wrong-2nd-argument-type. Здесь очень хорошо описана ответственность для super и extended

Comment: Еще может пригодиться этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361807

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Да, `<? super Number>` действительно подразумевает "любой тип, являющийся супер-классом для `Number`". Плюс сам `Number`.

По этой причине вы можете передать в метод, например, `List<Object>`.

Так как тип элементов в этом списке "что-то, являющееся суперклассом для `Number`", то можно добавлять в список элементы, тип которых является дочерним для `Number`. Например, `Integer`:

```
public void add(List<? super Number> list)
{
    list.add(1);
}
```

Это позволительно, так как в список можно добавлять элементы, тип которых является дочерним для типа элементов списка. Как в случае с обычным `List<Number>`:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
```

Однако вы не можете добавить в список `new Object()`, потому что нет никаких гарантий того, что в списке можно хранить элементы типа `Object`: под `?` может "скрываться" не только `Object`, но и, например, сам `Number`. В случае других классов (`? super X`), имеющих промежуточные классы между `Object` и самим `X` - ещё и любой промежуточный класс.

Так как истинный тип элементов списка неизвестен (`?`), но любой класс имеет в качестве суперкласса `Object`, то с полученным из списка элементом можно работать только как с `Object`. Даже с той единицей, которую только что туда сами и положили.

---

В случае `<? extends Number>` подразумевается "любой тип, являющийся дочерним классом для `Number`". Плюс сам `Number`.

В этом случае вы сможете передать в метод, например, `List<integer>`.

Так как тип элементов "что-то, являющееся дочерним классом для `Number`", то вы ничего не сможете добавить в список (кроме, разве что, `null`), ибо неизвестно что именно там может храниться.

А вот с полученным из списка элементом вы сможете работать как с `Number`:

```
public static void add2(List<? extends Number> list)
{
    int value = list.get(0).intValue();
}
```

Потому что какие бы там ни были элементы в списке, но они определённо из дочерних для `Number` классов, а, значит, могут работать как `Number`.

Comment: тоесть <? super Number> надо читать по факту как <? extends Number>?? Так получается?

Comment: @Павел нет, не надо. Это две противоположности. `super Number` подразумевает родительские классы для `Number` (например, `Object`), а `extends Number` - дочерние классы (например, `Integer`).

Comment: я вот тоже не понял из ответа "почему?")) особенно прочитав в комментарии, что `super Number подразумевает родительские классы для Number (например, Object)`

Comment: Я тогда не понял ведь оно же так работает... Вы говорите: >>> Подобная конструкция говорит, что вы хотите работать со списком как со списком Number.<<< ту тогда и получается extends. А написано то super. Значит такая конструкция должна говорить "я хочу работать с элементами Number и Object - это и есть то что соответствует super.

Comment: @Павел и в случае `super`, и в случае `extends` вы хотите работать со списком как со списком `Number`. Однако в случае `super` вы разрешаете передавать в метод `List<Object>`, ибо `Object` является суперклассом для `Number`. а в случае `extends` - разрешаете передавать `List<Integer>`, ибо он является дочерним классом для `Number`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский переписал ответ. Надеюсь, теперь он понятнее и адресует большее количество вопросов, заданных автором в одном вопросе. И надеюсь, что нигде не опечатался и не ошибся.

Comment: @Павел переписал ответ и с информацией из комментариев, и с доп. информацией. Возможно, так будет понятнее.

Answer (score 5):

Все очень просто.

Определение `List`'a с `wildcard` вида `<? super Number>` обозначает, что в списке хранятся элементы *какого то типа* от которого наследуется `Number`.  Здесь не обязательно должен быть `Object`, там может быть и какой то промежуточный класс в иерархии наследования.

Например.
Есть классы `A,B,C`. `A` наследуется от `B`, `B` в свою очередь наследуется от `C`.
Если мы пишем `List<? super A>`, это значит что список может быть как `List<A>`,`List<B>` или `List<C>`. Соответственно, если придет `List<B>`  то положить туда элементы типа `C` , будет ошибкой. От этой ошибки компилятор вас и предупреждает.

Comment: Если мы пишем List<? super A> - это значит , что список может быть как List<A> или List<Object>.Поясните , почему список может быть как List<B> , List<C> если эти классы являются подклассами A

Comment: я в ответе привел иерархию A<-B<-C. класс А является потомком как класса B так и класса C. Под дженерик вида <? super A>  подпадают классы A,B,C и Object

Comment: Из чего вы делаете вывод, что B и C являются подклассами A? Выше по-русски написано, что А наследует B, В наследует C