# Применение джейнериков в JAVA

Tags: java

Может кто-то примести примеры в которых удобно использовать по типу

```
 <? supper String>
```

Не могу придумать ни одного примера где можно их использовать 
P.S буду так же благодарен, если кто-то скинет статью/книгу о удобствах применения всех типов

```
<?>
```

джейнериков

Comment: Обязательно с String придумывать?

Comment: @gil9red, вроде нет.

Comment: <? supper Какой_то_класс> - может пригодится, хотя я не использовал. И нельзя сделать наследника от String. String финальный класс. <?> - считай, что значение по умолчанию, когда не указал ни какого другого.

Comment: Еще один вопрос, в котором затрагивается тема: [Различия между extend и super в Generics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613240)