# Метасимвол <?> в дженериках

Tags: java, generics

Animal - абстрактный класс, Cat - наследник Animal.
Есть класс, параметризованный абстрактным классом Animal:

```
public class AnimalCage<T extends Animal> {
/**
 * Вместимость
 */
private int capacity;
/**
 * Коллекция для хранения животных
 */
private ArrayList<T> animals;
public AnimalCage(int n) {
    this.capacity = n;
    animals = new ArrayList<>(n);
}

/**
 * Садим животное типа T в клетку
 * @param a - животное, которым параметризован объект клетки
 */
public void add(T a) {
    animals.add(a);
}
```

В main объявляем клетку:

```
AnimalCage<? extends Animal> someCage;
```

Но инициализируем её как:

```
someCage = new AnimalCage<Cat>;
```

Все работает. Но при попытке положить в someCage объект класса Cat выдает ошибку:

```
someCage.add(cat);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скорее всего, в моей голове - недопонимание, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: `AnimalCage<? extends Animal> someCage;` => `AnimalCage<Animal> someCage;`?

Comment: я знаю, что можно передать абстрактный Animal и складывать туда его наследников. Мне непонятно почему мой код не работает

Comment: ну а что вот это `AnimalCage<? extends Animal> someCage;` должно означать?

Comment: @bidanocka вам известно такое понятие как *специализация* класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном примере для сажания в клетку котов Вы должны объявить ее как `AnimalCage<Animal>` или `AnimalCage<? super Animal>`.

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613240/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-extend-%D0%B8-super-%D0%B2-generics) почитайте