# В асинхронном методе не получается привести List<T> к IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, типы-данных, асинхронность

В коде

```
// #1
Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync_1()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return new List<string>();
    });
}
```

не срабатывает приведение `List<T>` к `IEnemerable<T>` - компилятор ругается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему? Какие ограничение тут накладывает асинхронный вызов?** Так как примеры 2 и 3 работают.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546907/178988

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело вот в чём. Перепишем ваш код для ясности так:

```
Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync_1()
{
    Task<List<string>> t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return new List<string>();
    });
    return t;
}
```

Ошибка компиляции происходит на строке `return t`.

Несмотря на то, что `List<string>` *является* (is-a) `IEnumerable<string>`, из этого не следует, что `Task<List<string>>` *является* `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`.

Более простой пример: если `string` есть подкласс `object`, почему `Queue<string>` не является `Queue<object>`? Потому что если бы это было так, то можно было бы написать:

```
Queue<object> q = new Queue<string>();
q.add(new object()); // в Queue<string> оказался не string!
```

---

Вы можете легко обойти проблему, преобразовав в `IEnumerable` раньше:

```
Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync_1()
{
    return Task.Run<IEnumerable<string>>(() =>
    {
        // возвращаемое значение преобразуется в IEnumerable<string>
        return new List<string>();
    });
}
```

---

Для знатоков: это следствие общего факта: классы в C# *не ковариантны* по генерик-параметрам.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Why isn't there generic variance for classes in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734070/276994)

Comment: Эм.. Но IEnumerable неизменяемый...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это не поможет, `Task<T>` всё равно не ковариантен по `T`.

Comment: Ну так и расскажи, что такого можно сделать именно с таском. Очереди неинтересны.

Comment: `return new List<string>() as IEnumerable<string>;` прокатит?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вопрос не в том, что можно и чего нельзя сделать. Ковариантности нет, потому что в объявлении `Task<T>` нет ключевого слова `out T`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, так прокатит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61955/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).