# Какая разница сущестует между IEnumerable<TEntity> и Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>>?

Tags: c#, task

Так все ОК

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

Но стоит попытаться сделать так

```
public virtual Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get()
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
}
```

и вы получите ошибку неявного приведения `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<TEntity>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>>'`

Задать данный вопрос во многом сподвиг меня вот этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/690655/222542) на похожий вопрос.
На мой скромный взгляд, данный ответ не объясняет ничего. Да, ковариантность в случае обобщений не работает, хотя постойте, в первом же примере все ОК, или нет? Или ковариантность перестает работать только в случае `Task<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом примере ковариантности и нет вовсе - у вас тип обобщённого параметра остаётся прежним, `TEntity`, а меняется тип самого контейнера. Так как класс `List<TEntity>`реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, ошибок нет. А во втором случае как раз проявляется та самая неработающая ковариантность, о которой говорилось в упомянутом вами ответе.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Во втором случае тоже контейнер меняется, разве нет?

Comment: @Bulson во втором случае вы возвращаете не контейнер, а таск, параметризованный контейнером. При этом, как и писал  @VladD в упомянутом вами ответе, класс `Task<T>` не является ковариантным, соответственно второй пример не работает.

Comment: Спасибо, за разъяснение. Все дело оказалось в моем неверном "восприятии" параметризированного таска.

Comment: @Bulson поддержка ковариантности и контравариантности в C# реализована только для интерфейсов и делегатов.

Comment: @sp7 не понял ваш комментарий. Как это можно "пришпилить" к моему вопросу?

Comment: @Bulson это я по поводу вашего второго примера.

Comment: @sp7 это вы к тому, что таски не являются интерфейсами или делегатами?

Comment: @Bulson да, потому что `Task` и `Task<T>` это класс.

Comment: @sp7 спасибо, за уточнение.