# Ковариантность и контрвариантность в делегатах Action и Func

Tags: c#, action, делегаты

Почему параметры `T1`, `T2`,... являются контрвариантными (`in T1`, `in T2`,...) в `Action`? 

И почему возвращаемый тип в `Func` является ковариантным (`out TResult`)?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516687/10105

Comment: @VladD, а почему не закроете как дубликат?

Comment: @Андрей: Потому что не уверен на 100%

Comment: @VladD отчасти дубликат... Априори знал что такое ковариантность/контрвариантность и как. Вопрос был по поводу архитектурного решения: почему в делегатах именно так. Исходя из ответов, всё встало на свои места. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На пальцах: если вам требуется парикмахер для собак (`Action<Dog>`), подойдёт универсальный парикмахер для животных (функция, принимающая на вход `Animal`).

Поэтому переменной типа `Action<Dog>` можно присвоить выражение типа `Action<Animal>`.

---

Наоборот, если вам нужно раздобыть какое угодно животное (`Func<Animal>`), то магазин по продаже котяток подойдёт (`Func<Kitten>`).

Поэтому переменной типа `Func<Animal>` можно присвоить выражение типа `Func<Kitten>`.

---

Более подробно: [В чем суть ковариантности и контравариантности делегатов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516687/10105), [Контравариантность обобщенных делегатов С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/546904/10105).

Comment: Не согласен, если мне нужен парикмахер для собак, то мне никак не подойдёт общий парикмахер для животных. Парикмахер для всех животных не сможет (скорее всего) нормально постричь собаку.

Comment: @ixSci: Раз он декларирует себя парикмахером для всех животных, пусть стрижёт собаку. Если он не умеет стричь любое животное, а умеет только ёжиков, енотов и ехидн, то он никак не универсальный парикмахер.

Answer (score 4):

Делегаты `Action` контрвариантны потому что там, где вы можете использовать экземпляр класса-предка, там же вы можете использовать и экземпляр потомка. Пример:

```
Action<string> act1 = str => { int i  = str.Length; }; 
Action<object> act2 = o => { string s = o.ToString(); };
// вы можете сделать такое присваивание
act1 = act2;
// и затем вызвать делегат вот так, 
// потому что по факту у вас будет вызван 2-ой делегат, 
// которому будет передана string, производная от object
act1("10");
```

Так как `string` - наследник `object`, то вы можете делать с этим параметром всё то же, что и с `object`. Ошибки нет.
При этом вы не можете сделать так:

```
act2 = act1;
```

Потому что в этом случае вы смогли бы передать некий `object` в метод, требующий на самом деле `string`, а это уже ошибка.

Схожим образом объясняется и ковариантность `Func`:

```
Func<string> func1 = () => "str";
Func<object> func2 = () => 10;
// такое присваивание тоже возможно 
func2 = func1;
// ваш делегат вернёт некий object, который по факту является строкой. 
object r = func2();
```

Аналогично предыдущему примеру, нельзя делать так:

```
func1 = func2;
```

так как в этом случае делегату, возвращающему `string`, вы можете присвоить делегат, возвращающий `object` (который в нашем примере фактически имеет тип `int`).