# Создание массива листов. c#

Tags: c#

Я хочу создать массив Листов, где шаблон будет интерфейсом, а элементы массива- листы, унаследованных от него классов.
Следующий код работает:

```
IWorker Worker = new ordinaryWorker();
```

(и не удивительно)
Однако следующий:

```
List<IWorker>[]  Workers = new List<IWorker>[8];
Workers[0] = new List<ordinaryWorker>();
```

нет. В чем проблема?
IWorker - интерфейс
ordinaryWorker- унаследованный от него класс

Comment: "следующий: ... нет." - что это значит?

Comment: Это значит, что предыдущий код не работает (Однако следующий: ... нет.)

Comment: Что значит "код не работает"? Маленький гномик высовывается из компьютера, говорит "Код не работает!" и смеется?

Comment: Да, прямо так и происходит и имя этому гномику компилятор, который отказывается компилировать

Comment: Если Вам охота валять дурака, то свой минус я уже поставил.

Comment: Мне охота разобраться в проблеме, если вы готовы мне помочь, я с радостью приму вашу помощь, если нет, то до свидания

Comment: вы хотите разобраться, но не пишите ошибку....хммм...странный способ ХОТЕТЬ :)

Comment: [Видосик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvmvcHroPRg) в тему.

Comment: @Bulson да, вот в этом и ошибка, спасибо большое

Comment: Ко/контр-вариантность.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546907/178988

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По соглашению C# названия типов начинаются с большой буквы, поэтому я буду писать название `OrdinaryWorker` именно так. Вы тоже лучше переделайте у себя, потому что другие программисты с трудом будут понимать ваш код.

Теперь ответ на ваш вопрос.

Тип `List<OrdinaryWorker>` нельзя приводить к `List<IWorker>` из-за этого, что тип `List<T>` *инвариантен* относительно `T`.

*Инвариантен* означает что тип `List<A>` приводим к `List<B>` только в том случае, если `A` и `B` — это один и тот же тип.

Почему в случае списков действует такое строгое правило? Потому что *инвариантность* в данном случае защищает вас от странных трудно уловимых ошибок времени выполнения.

Предположим, что у вас есть три класса: `Animal`, `Cat` и `Dog`, то есть *Животное*, *Кошка* и *Собака*. `Animal` это абстрактный класс или интерфейс, а `Cat` и `Dog` — два соседа-наследника `Animal`. Соседа в том смысле, что *Кошки* и *Собаки* не являются наследниками друг друга.

Если бы не инвариантность списка, вы могли бы написать:

```cs
// выглядит, как список животных, хотя внутри список кошек
List<Animal> cats = new List<Cat>();
animals.Add(new Cat()); // всё хорошо: засунули кошку в список кошек
animals.Add(new Dog()); // выполнится, хотя засунули собаку в список кошек

foreach(Cat cat in cats)  // где-то здесь на собаке цикл сломается
{
   . . .
}
```

Корень проблемы здесь в том, что вы можете изменять исходный список, добавляя в него другие объекты. Если бы вы не могли этого делать, приведение типов было бы безопасным.

Посмотрим на интерфейс `IReadOnlyList<T>`, это список только для чтения. `List<T>` его реализует. Можем ли мы писать так?

```
IReadOnlyList<Animal> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

Оказывается, да. Это возможно потому, что в `IReadOnlyList` в отличие от `List` нет методов или свойств, изменяющих состояние списка. Вы берёте список кошек, делаете из него список животных, но вы не можете изменить этот список. Значит, собака там не появится

Тип `IReadOnlyList<T>` называется *ко-вариантным* относительно `T`. Это значит, что если тип `A` переводится в `B` (`A` это потомок `B`, который всегда неявно можно привести к своему родительскому типу), то и `IReadOnlyList<A>` неявно приводится к `IReadOnlyList<B>`.

Ну а поскольку `List<B>` это наследник `IReadOnlyList<B>` (мы всегда можем привести класс к любому из интерфейсов, которые он реализует), мы неявно можем привести `List<B>` к `IReadOnlyList<A>`:

```
// при условии, что A это интерфейс, а B реализация
// или при условии, что A это базовый класс, а B наследник
IReadOnlyList<A> list = (IReadOnlyList<A>)(IReadOnlyList<B>)(new List<B>());
```

Я тут явно записал два неявных приведения, которые компилятор сделает для нас.
Тот факт, что `IReadOnlyList<T>` ко-вариантен относительно `T` указывается при описании интерфейса `IReadOnlyList` с помощью ключевого слова **out**:

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<out T>,
                                        IEnumerable<out T>
{
    . . .
}
```

Запись **out T** в данном случае имеет интерпретацию: `T` может быть только выходным параметром или результатом метода. Именно поэтому нельзя добавить в интерфейс методы `Add(T obj)` или `Remove(T obj)`, но можно `T At(int n)`.

Мы тут получаем странный побочный эффект, который, к сожалению, нельзя исправить в C#. Иногда наши методы получают объекта типа `T` в качестве параметра, но не изменяют список. Таков, например, метод `bool Contains(T obj)`. К сожалению, поскольку у компилятора нет способа разобраться в том, изменяет метод список или нет, он не допустит такой метод у интерфейса, где `T` объявлен, как `out`.

Поэтому в `IReadOnlyList<T>` и `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` нет метода `Contains`.

Answer (score 3):

Нужен апкаст.

```csharp
Workers[0] = new List<ordinaryWorker>() as List<IWorker>;
```